# Root category as frontpage

Tags: magento2, home-page

How do I get my root category included in navigation etc as my frontpage? I can't find the answer! I tried to put in a widget but that's not the same!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get all categories for a store:

```
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    $data = []
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    parent::__construct($data);
}

$categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$categories = $categoryFactory->create()                              
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore()); //categories from current store will be fetched

foreach ($categories as $category){
    $category->getName();
}
```

Comment: i know, but how i get them as my frontpage?

Comment: Go to your theme and open header.phtml and write this code there.

Comment: thats not what i want, i want on the fronpage exact a page as a category page, but now for the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the products with the widget functionality.

You will have to first login as an administrator to your Magento 2 based store’s back end.

Than Navigate to **Content > Pages**.

Here you will see a list of your store’s pages and by clicking on the Select option you will be able to Edit your home page.

Click on the Content tab and click on the insert widget button to add a widget for this page.

Now you will be able to choose one of the widget types available. Choose Catalog New product List to feature the newest products from the catalog on the main page.

You will also be able to select the number of products on the screen as well as the exact way they are being displayed.

When you are ready get back to the Content tab by clicking on the Insert Widget button and then click the Save Page button to apply the changes to the page.

Comment: I did that, but that's not working good!! See here (http://www.targetcars.eu) That's a widget. As you click on the navigation below the page,  it goes always to page 1 the first time